# meta_value_num sort glitch

Tags: custom-field, query-posts, meta-query

i have a custom query, and I have a meta key that contains a sequence number: 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2... 11.1, etc

the problem occurs when the numerical sequence gets in to double digits, ie. 5.11, 5.12, 5.21

these appear as such

5.1, 5.11, 5.12, 5.2, 5.21 etc instead of 5.1, 5.2, 5.3... 5.11, 5.12 etc

how can I make them sort properly!?

```
$loop = new WP_Query(array(
    'factsheet_category' => $term->slug,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 
    'meta_key' => 'factsheet_id', 
    'order' => 'ASC'
));
```

Answer (score 1):

You want [natural order sorting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php),

Example;

```
$val = array(5.1, 5.11, 5.12, 5.2, 5.21);
natsort($val);
foreach ($val as $key => $val) {
    echo $val."<br>";
}

Produces:

5.1
5.2
5.11
5.12
5.21
```

Where as;

```
$val = array(5.1, 5.11, 5.12, 5.2, 5.21);
asort($val);
foreach ($val as $key => $val) {
    echo $val."<br>";
}

Produces:

5.1
5.11
5.12
5.2
5.21
```

### Solution

```
$loop = new WP_Query(array(
    'factsheet_category' => $term->slug,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value meta_value_num', //addition of meta_value before meta_value_num
    'meta_key' => 'factsheet_id', 
    'order' => 'ASC'
));
```

Comment: sounds logical, but it doesn't make a difference - they are still sorted as per your second example :(

Comment: +1 for the answer... @ElleBillias It does. Just use a `natsort()` call to the _result_.

Comment: How would I go about that? I adde the extra orderby value but it didn't change. How can I add natsort() to it?